# Create a database schema-script in ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express

I have a fully functional database in sql server. Around 40 tables. I have to install this schema (only the schema, not the data) on multiple other sql server instances. SSMS offers a nice way to auto generate schemas using Tasks --> Generate Scripts. It kinda works, but I am not sure if I understand it correctly:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [history] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [isdeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RecGroupData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [rid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END

GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF_TableName_id]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [id]
END
--Just showing one ALTER TABLE and IF NOT EXISTS. The others are generated in the same way.
```

What happens, if I execute the script, create a new script with the exact same content, but add a new column to it (--> `id`, `history`, `isdeleted` and `timestamp`)? Does it automatically add the new line? I think yes, of course, but I don't get, how it would know, if the column should be `NOT NULL`, `VARCHAR`, `BIT`, or something similar. It would just execute

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [id]
```

(`id` => new sample column)
But there isn't any information about the data type or any other modifiers.
Also, if I execute my script like this one a second time, it'll throw some errors:

> Meldung 1781, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 3
>   An die Spalte ist bereits ein DEFAULT-Wert gebunden.

Which translates to this:

> Message 1781, level 16, status 1, line 3
>   A DEFAULT value is already bound to the column.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you asking two separate questions - how to add a column to a table, and "why do I get message 1781"?

Comment: Yes, and where is the problem? Two questions instead of one, isn't that okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that there was a default value assigned to that column before. 
Also:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [id]
```

is not the syntax for adding new column - this is to add default value of [NEWID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) to the column [id].
To add a column you you should follow [this steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms190238(v=sql.110).aspx) (with an example inside).
Also how would the SQL Server know the setup settings for the new columns from your manually added lines? It would simply allow you to define them as you want and accept if the syntax is right or through an error if not during the script parse process (can be done by [ctrl] + [F5] in SSMS).